# fix first and last divs css

Tags: html, css-position, fixed, horizontal-scrolling

i want Fix first and last divs when i tying scrool on this example [jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jy0hmh9g/3/) like on [this image](http://f-picture.net/lfp/s58.radikal.ru/i162/1410/8d/e1eb77ea4ddb.jpg/htm).

i tried on tablet but it is not working

Here is css

```
.mother_div {
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    width:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
.child_divs {
    height:40px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    background:green;
    display:block;
    width:1000px;
}
.child_divs div {
    float:left;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:15px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
.child_divs div:first-child {
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;
}
.child_divs div:last-child {
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: i am not able to understand, can you explain exactly what you want t achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
.child_divs div:first-child {
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}

.child_divs div:first-child + div {margin-left: 100px;}
.child_divs div:last-child {
    background:#ccc;
    color:#000;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jy0hmh9g/4/

Comment: Hi thanks for answer.

Yes i tried this method, but when site content is big before this table, it don't working 
http://jsfiddle.net/qnrv29xj/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### Solution 1:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qnrv29xj/)**

```
.child_divs div:first-child {
    position:fixed;
}
.child_divs div:last-child {
    position:fixed;
    left:409px;
}
.child_divs div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

### Solution 2:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5sbxa3az/)**

```
.child_divs div:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
}
.child_divs div:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
}
.child_divs div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```